# Looping through all rows in single column and altering string values of each element in shapefile using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, typeerror

I have a shapefile with an attribute table that partially looks like this:

```
Row | Shape | Date
0   | Poly  | 05-Sep-10 16:12:00
1   | Poly  | 06-Sep-10 17:23:01
```

Is there a simple method that I can loop through the 'Date' column and add a `20` before the `10` in each cell? So that the output looks like this:

```
Row | Shape | Date
0   | Poly  | 05-Sep-2010 16:12:00
1   | Poly  | 06-Sep-2010 17:23:01
```

`Date` fields are `text` format.

I have been able to hand edit multiple rows, but let's say I have 10,000 rows, this would take a considerable amount of time.

Attempt using ArcPy in ArcMap:

```
import arcpy

path='C:/path/to/file.dbf'

field='Date' #name of the second column

twenty = '20'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(path, field) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:
        new_row = row[0][:7] + twenty + row[0][7:]
        row = new_row
        print(row)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Error I receive with this is:

> TypeError: sequence of size must match the size of the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
row = new_row
```

to:

```
row = (new_row)
```

or:

```
row = [new_row]
```

I suspect your cursor needs either a list or tuple returned to it.  That list or tuple will contain your single string.

Personally, I would do it, as [@smiller commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339707/looping-through-all-rows-in-single-column-and-altering-string-values-of-each-ele/339864?noredirect=1#comment554843_339864), using something more like:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(path, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = "{}20{}".format(row[0][:7],row[0][7:])
        print(row)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the pythonic (and universal) way of doing this is to convert those dates from string to `datetime` object and reformatting by using string directives. In your case, in a new field and using field calculator by **Show Codeblock** option:

Pre-logic script:

`import datetime`

new_field =

`datetime.datetime.strptime(!Date!,'%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')`